# How to embed Lucida Sans regular font using font-face in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I embed Lucida Sans regular font using `font-face` and it is working fine on all browsers except IE9. I used `font-face` something like this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Lucida-Sans-regular';
 src: url('../fonts/Lsans.eot');
 src: local('Lucida sans'), url('../fonts/Lsans.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Lsans.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Lsans.svg') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Can anyone help to make it working on IE9?

Comment: Silly question - do you have a `../fonts/Lsans.eot` ?

Comment: What about adding and .eot version? You seem to be missing that.

Comment: @karthikr: sorry for the silly question. It would be great if can hlep me. and ya .eot is there

Comment: I dint mean yours is a silly question. Mine was a silly question :) Do you have it.. Sorry to confuse you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is recommended to do the following :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see ... I've deleted that

Comment: @Xaltar great bit of copy and pasting. Does this work, have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that worked for me:

```
 url('../fonts/Lsans.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
```

Thanks!